# Android: Value out of JSONObject/responseListener

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences, response

I try to save the userid to work with it in a different Activity, but I was not able to get the value out of the try catch statement. I should mention that I am new to Android. (Also the AlertDialog is not working but that is not important). Thanks for help!
EDIT: I just found this out: The code down below is for the "First Screen" (shown by the first start of the App) and after you click on the button you will get to the MainActivity. If I close the App after the First Screen opened MainActivity, and open it again, the SharedPreferences are working perfectly.

```
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(View v) {


                                      next_page(v);

                                  }

    });
}

public void next_page(View v){


    final String firstname1 = firstnameFS.getText().toString();
    final String lastname1 = lastnameFS.getText().toString();
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response){

            try{
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean success =jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                int userid = jsonResponse.getInt("userid");

                if(success){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstScreen.this);
                    builder3.setMessage("Updated! Id:"+userid);
                    builder3.create().show();
                    SharedPreferences mySPR = getSharedPreferences("MySpFile", MODE_PRIVATE);

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySPR.edit();

                   editor.putString("firstnameSP", firstname1);
                   editor.putInt("useridSP", userid);

                   editor.commit();

                }else{
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstScreen.this);
                    builder.setMessage("Update Failed");
                    builder.create().show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    RegisterRequestFS registerRequestFS =new RegisterRequestFS(firstname1,lastname1, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(FirstScreen.this);
    queue.add(registerRequestFS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your shared preferences edit command inside the if(success) block.
After committing the useridSP inside your shared preference retrieve it with this code:

```java
SharedPreferences mySPR = getSharedPreferences("MySpFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
mySPR.getInt("useridSP",-1);
```

-1 value stays for default value, so be aware that if you get -1 for the useridSP in the new activity you're doing something wrong

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that before, but than i always get the default value, so -1

Comment: Are you sure that "success" variable is true? What's the value of jsonResponse.getInt("userid");?

Comment: Yes, i also just put in "true" for a test. In both cases it works after i close and open the App again (see my EDIT: above). Do you know why? I start the MainActivity over new Intent and than startActivity(intent), after my last code you can see above. Maybe I have to use something else than startActivity? In the MainActivity i load the SharedPref. with onCreate()

Comment: I don't get it, the main activity normally is the first activity of the app. In which activity are you executing the code above? May you show me your manifest.xml file?

Comment: If you download the app and open it for the FIRST TIME you will see the "FirstScreen" Activity with the code above where the user can register. If you open the App for the second time (third,...) you will immediately go to the "MainActivity". I hope it is better to understand now:)